# Can 0 be an eigenvalue?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, sobolev-spaces, mathematical-physics, spectral-theory

Let $-\Delta $ be the positive Laplacian and consider the operator 
$$
-\Delta + V
$$
on $L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$ with domain the Sobolev space $W^{2,2}(\mathbb{R}^3)$.  Here $V:\mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}$ is smooth, has compact support and acts by multiplication, $(Vf)(x)=V(x)f(x)$. Is it possible for $0$ to be an eigenvalue? That is, is it possible (for some choice of $V$), to find $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$ such that 
$$
-\Delta f + Vf = 0 \qquad ?
$$

Comment: The case $V\geq 0$ can be excluded, because in this case we have unicity of solutions. Also, it is worth to note that the problem is equivalent to know whether the function $I(u)=\frac{1}{2}\int |\nabla u|^2+\int Vu^2$ has additional critical points. Also, if the domain is bounded, or has a Poincare inequality, then we can find $V$ such that $0$ is a eigenvalue.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The domain is unbounded in this case.

Comment: this article may be of interest to you: http://link.springer.com/article/10.1140%2Fepjd%2Fe2009-00074-0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me put an incomplete idea here in the hope that others might be able to improve on it.

Let $q\geq0$ be a compactly supported smooth function in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and let $u$ be its Newtonian potential, i.e.,
$$
\Delta u = q.
$$
We know that $u$ is smooth, entirely subharmonic, and harmonic outside the support of $q$. We also know that $u$ decays at infinity, so by the maximum principle, $u$ is nonpositive. Moreover, because of the strong maximum principle, $u$ cannot attain the value $0$, hence $u<0$. Now we let $Q=q/u$, which is well defined because $u$ does not vanish anywhere. With this, we have
$$
- \Delta u + Qu = 0.
$$
The catch is that we cannot guarantee $u\in W^{2,2}(\mathbb{R}^3)$.
In general all we can say is $u$ decays like $1/|x|$, which is not enough for $u\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$. To get more decay, one must require $\int q=0$, and then we cannot guarantee $u\neq0$ everywhere. This makes the division $q/u$
 problematic.